# How to check whether large command text answer contains a specific string

Tags: u-boot

This is related to u-boot.

I looked at this link ([How to test the return of a command in U-Boot CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381641/how-to-test-the-return-of-a-command-in-u-boot-cli)) but it doesn't cover what I need. I also checked some other pages related to the 'test' command in u-boot but I can't figure out how to do what I would like. So there it is.

I have a u-boot command on a SBC which returns a set of information as text printed on the screen, where some part are strings representing versions. What I would like is to check whether the command return contains some specific strings to choose automatically what to do.

I have seen a few 'test' command help, but I couldn't figure out how to do this type of check on the text returned by this command. My goal is to have a set of nested ifs to choose in the different cases, or anything equivalent. If regex can be used, they perhaps could be helpful.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In U-Boot's hush shell there is no support for pipes. There is also no command like grep. So there are no means to succeed via U-Boot's built-in shell commands.

If you have access to the source of the command that you are executing, you could change it and use function env_set() to write the relevant data to environment variables and then use test for your purposes.